# Function that accepts an Array and a Number and returns the first index of the Number if found in the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, undefined

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

**Create a function that accepts an array and a number and returns the first index at which the value exists or -1 if the value is not found.**

Below is my attempt at it which seems to work fine when running the code on my own, but isn't accepted as a correct solution Err!  Any help is appreciated.

```
indexOf = function (arr, num) {

    var idx = arr.indexOf(num);

    for (i=0; i < arr.lenth; i++);

    if (idx !== -1) {return idx}
    else {return -1}
  }
  console.log(indexOf([25, 33, 45, 33, 23, 20], 33))
```

Comment: Does this resolves your issue?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/BaoLGjv

Comment: It seems to work when i run your code, but it's still not an accepted solution.  When i test both yours and my code i get the correct answer followed by ```=> Undefined```.  I think that has something to do with why it's not being accepted.

Comment: Syntactically your code is missing essential keywords and then it has a crapload of unnecessary loops and flow control....etc.

Comment: I can't say I disagree with you.  I'm very new at this which is why I'm here asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are trying to solve intends on you not using the built-in *indexOf*, otherwise there is no problem to solve.

Instead of providing you with the code to a solution, I'll give the process that you should go through to solve the problem.

1. Loop through the array, starting from index 0 and ending at the end of the array
2. In each iteration compare the number that has been provided to the value in the array at the current index
3. If the values match, simply return that index
4. If the loop completes without returning, it is safe to assume the number is not present in the array and so you must return -1

I hope this helps.